# win10 share internet using two devices

Tags: networking, wireless-networking

I have two wireless adapters, and I want to share internet from my computer using win10 hotspot functionnality, so what I want to do is: 
one of the two devices connects to a WiFi and the other device share the internet again using wifi, so one connects to a far wifi and the other re shares the wifi.
win10 doesn't allow this, as the same device that connects to the far wifi is the same one that re shares the internet.

Comment: If both devices have a WiFI adapter why don't you just connect both devices to the same WiFi access point?

Comment: So you want the computer to behave like a wifi range extender? Or are you sharing a "different" wireless network? Perhaps we can solve your root problem rather than this secondary one: why are you trying to do this? What problem are you trying to solve with this setup?

Comment: @music2myear yeah I want my computer to behave like a wifi range extender, I want to this because the first adapter is connected to my pc using a usb extension cable so if I used it to share internet, the signal is weak on my phone, and because sharing internet affects the wifi speed, that's why I want another device to re share internet

Comment: I could be wrong but I don't think your one single wireless device can be both server and client at the same time.  As in, if you enable AP mode (access point).. I don't believe that you can use that same adapter (at the same time) to get its service from somewhere else.  Typically, ICS is done by using an ethernet port for your access to the internet and the wifi adapter as an access point.  Please someone correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: actually it does works with one wireless adapter, one adapter can behave as range extender, I just want the resharing to be done with a another wireless adapter on the same pc